# Python:Error while trying to sort a set alphabetically

Tags: python, list, set, python-3.6

I am trying to sort a set alphabetically. This is the statement I am using:

```
for sentence in corpus:
    allword=allword.union(set(sentence.split(' ')))
    allword=sorted(allword)
```

I am getting an error "'list' object has no attribute 'union'". But I am not getting this error if I remove the code to sort. That is, the code is completely working in this case:

```
allword=allword.union(set(sentence.split(' ')))
```

But when I add the second line I am getting error.
Could someone please help me understand why this weird behavior? Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: `sorted` returns a list. But if you're using a set anyway why do you need to sort? Sets aren't ordered.

Comment: Are you calling these commands in a loop? At the beginning `allword` is `set`, and then `sorted()` will change `allword` to `list`. Second iteration you will get error - list doesn't have `union()` method.

Comment: I need to get the contents of this set in alphabetical order.

Comment: @andrej Yes..I am calling in a loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you are calling these commands in a loop: At the beginning allword is set, and then sorted() will change allword to list. Second iteration you will get error - list doesn't have union() method.

The solution is to remove `sorted()` from the loop and do it only at the end once:

```
corpus = [
    'I am trying to sort a set alphabetically',
    'This is the statement I am using'
]


allword = set()

for sentence in corpus:
    allword=allword.union(sentence.split(' '))

print( sorted(allword) )
```

Prints:

```
['I', 'This', 'a', 'alphabetically', 'am', 'is', 'set', 'sort', 'statement', 'the', 'to', 'trying', 'using']
```